# add checkbox yes and no in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have extjs form, I need to add 2 checkbox next to each other. my field lable will be "Allow" and checkbox title is "Yes and "No"

My code:

```
{
            fieldLabel: 'Allow',

        },
```

Comment: I suggest you to put a little bit of effort on your work. Hint: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
{
    fieldLabel: 'allow',
    xtype:'toolbar',
    items:[{
        xtype:'checkbox',
        fieldLabel: 'CB1',
        name: 'CB1'
    },
    {
        xtype:'checkbox',
        fieldLabel: 'CB1',
        name: 'CB1'
    }]
}
```

Comment: {
   fieldLabel: 'Allow',
   xtype:'checkboxgroup',
   items:[{
    boxLabel: 'a',
             name: 'checkboxA',
             inputValue: 'a',
             checked: true
         }, {
             boxLabel: 'b',
             name: 'checkboxB',
             inputValue: 'b'
   }]
  }